# Calculating volatility percentage for a given time period

Tags: volatility, liquidity

I am looking at an EMEA liquidity report.

One measure I am interested in is the volatility. The report includes a list of various indexes and the "Average Volatility " for a period of 5 days expressed as a percentage.

I can't make sense of how this is calculated.

I have the underlying figures that allow me to try to calculate this metric, but I can't understand how it was calculated that FTSE100 had an Volatility of 59% between the between the 2nd and 6th of March. 59% percent of what??

Any leads/ideas as to how this metric can be found would be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Volatility is typically expressed as an annualized standard deviation of periodic movements. so a "59% volatility" most likely means that there's a 68% (1 sd) chance that the index will move 59% (up or down) or less in 1 year (~252 business days). To convert an annual volatility to a daily one, you divide by the square root of 252 (# of trading days in a typical year), so the daily volatility for that period was

```
59% / sqrt(252) = 3.7%.
```

That means in that period there was about a 68% chance that the daily change is 3.7% or less (or, that there's a 32% change that the daily change will be *more* than 3.7%).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, instructive. My question is more about how the actual 78% value (was 78, not 59) was actually calculated. For STOXX 600, for the period of time from 2nd and 6th of March, they calculate an 'Avg volatility %' of 78%, I have the opening, closing, high and low prices for that index. How can I arrive at that figure. Doing a simple standard deviation on the days' price doesn't seem to do it. Thanks –

Comment: What standard deviation do you get? Take the sd of daily _returns_ (% change from previous day) and multiply it by sqrt(252)

Comment: For the sake of giving you numbers, the standard deviation of the % change of the stoxx 600 (https://www.investing.com/indices/stoxx-600-historical-data) between the 9th and 13th of march is 0.053851. Times sqrt(252) is 0.85 which I guess translates to 85%. The report gives this value as 78%, so there is a bit of discrepency there.